# Launch process under windows session user when impersonating

Tags: c#, impersonation

I have a desktop application (not a service) that can be run using process impersonation. I achieve this by having a separate application which is used as a launcher, and uses CreateProcessWithLogonW to run the application under a different user.  Upon the user signing-out of the application, I need to figure out how to make the application run the launcher process under the credentials of the windows session user without prompting for the password.

My current strategy is:

1. Use ProcessIdToSessionId to get the session id from the application process.
2. Use WTSQueryUserToken to get the primary user token from the session id.
3. Use DuplicateTokenEx for something that isn't exactly clear to me.
4. Use CreateProcessAsUser to run the process.

Currently, WTSQueryUserToken fails with result ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840(v=vs.85).aspx).  Is there a different way that I can get that token?  Is there another strategy entirely that would work for this?

Also, I am using C# and am fairly new with P/Invokes. Thanks

Comment: Which user is running the app and who is being impersonated? How do you identify the user to be impersonated?

Comment: User A is logged into windows.  The application launcher exe is run under user A, and user B types in credentials, which then starts the application under user B. The application then needs to start the launcher process under user A without a password prompt.  To detect impersonation, I get the username of the windows session user through WTSQuerySessionInformation, and compare it to the Environment.UserName property.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use WTSQuerUserToken in this scenario.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840(v=vs.85).aspx

"To call this function successfully, the calling application must be running within the context of the LocalSystem account and have the SE_TCB_NAME privilege."

I still don't understand how many exe's you have and how many processes are being executed and more importantly why. Perhaps you could explain in more detail?

If the original launcher is still running it might be simpler to message it and tell it to do stuff instead of launch another one from your impersonated process.